# Highstock - Enable marker only on broken line

Tags: highcharts

To ease graph readability, I've turned markers off on my highstock spline chart (markers : enabled : false). I also wanted to broke the graph in case of irregular interval between data and so I have successfully set the gapSize to 1. However, this has the bad side of hidding single data that are not linked from one side or an other.

Here's an example (you'll easily see that some of the points are hidden) : http://jsfiddle.net/qosdc6hr

```
series: [{
    marker:{
        enabled:false
    },     
    gapSize: 5,
    [...] 
 }]
```

I want to have these single points drawn on the chart to make them visible at first glance. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you paste the full and minimal code or make a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle?

Comment: Question has been edited in order to provide jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

You can enable marker for a specific point like this:

```
data: [
    { x: Date.UTC(1970, 9, 27), y: 0, marker: { enabled: true }},
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3eco7Lmz/